# Dropping Multiple Columns using Columns.Str.Startswith

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns, startswith

I have a data set with 204 rows x 507 columns. As I understand, in order to drop columns containing the word 'Dog' for example, you would use:

`df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.startswith('Dog')]`

I also understand that you can drop columns using multiple criteria, for example 'Dog' and 'Cat' by using the following 'str.contains' code:

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.contains('Dog|Cat')]
```

However it appears that when you apply the '|' (or) function to "columns.str.startswith" as below it does not work and the output gives 204 rows x 0 columns

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.startswith('Dog|Cat')]
```

Out `204 rows × 0 columns`

**Why is this? Is there a method to drop columns using multiple criteria using the "df.columns.str.startswith" function?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a couple of strings, I prefer regex approach:

```
 df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.match('^(Dog|Cat).*')]
```

Answer (score 2):

If want multiple values in [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) use `tuple` like:

```
df.loc[:,~df.columns.str.startswith(('Dog', 'Cat'))]
```